# Autofilling attribute fields with text using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator, sql, select-by-attribute

[image]

I have a shapefile containing over 18,500 polygons which are classified land uses of Ireland. I am trying to then put these classifications into a macroscale as per CAFRE directive - urban, suburban, rural and rural background.

I am using ArcGIS Pro and was wondering is there a way to write an SQL statement to state `WHERE Class_Desc is equal to Continuous Urban Fabric THEN Macroscale is equal to Urban`

Or something like that, a quicker and effective way of filling the rows rather than individually

Comment: That's a basic capability of Calculate Field. What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried Calculate field, but it isn't a numeric value I'm inserting. It is text

Comment: No difference. Dates are also calulate-able. The first example in the doc is even a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Calculate Field tool with a python expression.  The expression can be a long `if`, `elif`, `else` statement or you could use a dictionary lookup like below:

```
def get_value(class_desc):
    lookup = {
        'Continuous Urban Fabric': 'Urban',
        'Some other value': 'Other',
    }
    
    return lookup.get(class_desc)

__esri_field_calculator_splitter__
get_value(!CLASS_DESC!)
```

[image]